# Generate a two-digit positive random number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, random

How can I implement a simple function in JavaScript that generates a random positive number that consists of only two digits?

Comment: You mean, 0..99? 10..99?

Comment: What do you mean by "negative"? To get a specific range, just scale the uniform distribution, and then round to integers. I'm surprised you haven't found an example doing that.

Comment: This can't be the first question to scale and round random numbers. Candidate: *[Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/)*

Answer (score 24):

For a random number between 10 and 99, use:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10)
```

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zjLY6/

Comment: Isn't this subject to floating point rounding errors? What if 10, when converted to floating point just before the addition, is actually represented as 9.9999987183884837499393? Even if it happens to work for 10, it may not be generally applicable.

Comment: Shouldn't the 10 be outside the parentheses?

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
Math.random().toFixed(2)*100
```

Comment: This can give results like: `56.99999999999999`. It would be better to apply `Math.floor` to the result